# mysql unique for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

When payment happen, sometimes its captured double entry in table.
I want to ignore double entry capture so i want to insert records when these `created`, `user_id`, `amount` fields should be unique.
How do i make it ? Below is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`project_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`foreign_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`class` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`transaction_type_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`payment_gateway_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`gateway_fees` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
`is_old` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=266 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY created, user_id, amount`

Comment: Look into using table constraints.

Comment: It is incredibly unlikely that you would want a float data type in this table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly answer your question, you create a unique **composite** key on the combination of those 3 columns. That way no two rows can exist with a combination of the 3 of them in the composite index.

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions2` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`project_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`foreign_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`class` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`transaction_type_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`payment_gateway_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`gateway_fees` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
`is_old` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
unique key(created,user_id,amount) -- <------------------- right here
);
```

insert some data to test it:

```
insert transactions2 (created,modified,user_id,project_id,foreign_id,class,
transaction_type_id,amount,description,payment_gateway_id,gateway_fees,is_old) values
('2009-01-01 12:00:00','2009-01-01 12:00:00',666,1,1,'a',1,100,'desc',1,12,1);
```

-- inserts fine (above)

Try it again with exactly the same data:

```
insert transactions2 (created,modified,user_id,project_id,foreign_id,class,
transaction_type_id,amount,description,payment_gateway_id,gateway_fees,is_old) values
('2009-01-01 12:00:00','2009-01-01 12:00:00',666,1,1,'a',1,100,'desc',1,12,1);
```

-- error 1062: Duplicate entry

-- change it barely:

```
insert transactions2 (created,modified,user_id,project_id,foreign_id,class,
transaction_type_id,amount,description,payment_gateway_id,gateway_fees,is_old) values
('2009-01-01 13:00:00','2009-01-01 12:00:00',666,1,1,'a',1,100,'desc',1,12,1);
```

-- inserts fine

Also, use `ENGINE=INNODB`. Read about that [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html).

Please read [Mysql multi column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) a.k.a. composite indexes.

Lastly, the concept of what you are talking about is not far off from [Insert on Duplicate Key Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Just throwing that reference out there for you.

Comment: Um, amount would not normally form a component of a PK

Comment: Just answering it strictly, @Strawberry. I agree. And it is not a PK

Comment: but as @Strawberry is suggesting, you might want to re-think this whole thing

Comment: Like a transaction id must be unique, or another posting of a transaction id that already exists does an Insert on Duplicate Key Update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using ,handling at the time of inserting,

You can try `WHERE NOT EXISTS` with `INSERT`.

Something like this.(You need to specify column name who has `NOT NULL` constraint,i missed all those columns)

```
INSERT INTO table_name(`created`,`user_id`,`amount`) VALUES =
     '$created','$user_id','$amount'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
        FROM table_name 
           WHERE created ='$created' AND user_id='$user_id' AND amount='$amount')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: syntax error this way. Plus he has `not null` columns you ignore. You making up syntax again bro :)